# Time Out via Discord API

Tags: discord

How do I add a time out to a guild member via the Discord API?
This question is about the [new time out feature](https://support.discord.com/hc/en-us/articles/4413305239191-Time-Out-FAQ), not to be confused with [delays](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66187946/how-to-add-timeout-python-discord-bot) or [timers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47997226/command-timeout-discord-js)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to send a `PATCH` request to `/guilds/{guild.id}/members/{user.id}` and edit set the `communication_disabled_until` field to an ISO8601 timestamp which holds the date when the timeout will be disabled.

If you want to remove the timeout, simply set `communication_disabled_until` to `Null`

[discord-api reference](https://discord.com/developers/docs/resources/guild#modify-guild-member)