# How Can I Use Discord.js V14 Features in Discord.js V12?

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js, bots

So, I Make Discord Bots in Discord.js V12, The Changes in V13 and V14 Do not Suit me Well, So i Was Wondering, If there is a package That Lets me Use Discord.js V14 Features (I Am looking For the `.timeout` Function in Members, So i Can Timeout People. And Please Avoid Answering With "just upgrade to discord.js v14"

Comment: `Seeking recommendations for books, tools, software libraries, and more

This question is likely to lead to opinion-based answers.`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Time Out via Discord API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70444041/time-out-via-discord-api)

Comment: You cannot use a v14 feature in v12, but you can use the feature directly like in the question I marked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't just use a v13 or v14 feature in v12.

Discord.js v12 is deprecated and broken in some ways. I was using v11 because I didn't want to deal with Intents and slash commands (what I'm guessing you don't want to deal with). Someone recommended that I switched to v13 for these reasons, I did and making the bot went very smoothly, the intents weren't that big of an issue.

Not trying to simply "tell you to switch" but I think it would be good and beneficial in your case. If there's some other reason you don't want to switch, please say why.